# How to map html button with html image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, image

I am developing an application in asp.net. In my web page there is a Select Image Button. When user will click on it then a modal popup will appear on the screen with 10 images (The number of image is not fixed it may be n number of images). Each image will have a corresponding button called select. When user will select a particular image then that image will be displayed in main page. The problem is how can I understand which image's select button has been clicked. I have to fetch the path of the selected image. Please help me out from here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice to see what you have tried. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest mapping an ID to the button; and then in your code behind show images based on Button ID, or CommandArgument?

```
       <asp:ImageButton id="imagebutton1" runat="server"
       AlternateText="ImageButton 1"
       ImageAlign="left"
       ImageUrl="images/pict.jpg"
       OnClick="ImageButton_Click"
       CommandArgument ="1"
          />
```

Comment: I have meet this without server side control.. Please suggest me some JQuery or javascript sample..

Answer (score 0):

In my suggestion, try to add class for all images. Then give id to all that images dynamically. Now you can easily findout which image is selected.